# JWT encryption taking audience as array but need to send normal string instead

Tags: dart, encryption, jwt

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/jaguar_jwt/ to encrypt data but I have a situation, where I need to send the audience as `String` instead of `List<String>`. How can I do it, is there some workaround?

```
var claimSet = JwtClaim(
      issuer: issuer,
      subject: '',
      audience: [issuer],
      otherClaims: {'DATA': encodedPayload},
      maxAge: Duration(days: kReleaseMode ? 1 : 7),
 );

claimSet.audience = issuer; // Giving error - 'audience' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
```

I tried to update the `audience` key but IDE itself giving an error. It's not that I want to update the `issuer`, I just want the `audience` to be a String.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that since the `audience` is final.

> A variable with the final keyword will be initialized at runtime and
> can only be assigned for a single time

You have to create a new `JwtClaim` object whenever you want to update.

Updated: the `audience` cannot be a string since it is defined as a List in the source. Please refer to the source file link as below:

https://github.com/Jaguar-dart/session/blob/master/jaguar_jwt/lib/src/claim.dart

Comment: It is not that I want to update the `issuer`. I have the `audience` key to be a `String` instead of the List.

Comment: Sorry, I am mistyping. Updated the answer.

Comment: Even if I create a new JwtClaim, it is taking a List only.

Comment: Because the audience is defined as a list as mentioned in jwt rfc. Please refer: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#page-9